# Django returns algorithm result different to python interpreter

Tags: python, django, algorithm

I have some Algorithms Bubble, insertion, sort, merge etc.

I have coded them into a Django website so you can input an array of numbers and it will sort them into order.

To test i passed in this list of numbers:

`[3, 12, 5, 4, 8, 5, 1]`

When I run the function in a shell the algorithm returns what I want:

`[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 12]`

When I run it through Django the output is not what I want:

`[1, 12, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8]`

I have tried both POST and GET methods.

I have tried with and without for loops.

I have tried with and without CSRF_TOKENS.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from custom.bubble import maf_bubble

def algo(request):
    if request.GET:
        nums_list = maf_bubble(list(request.GET['numbers'].split(',')))
        rtn_res = render(request, 'algorithms/sort.html', {'results' : nums_list})
        return rtn_res
    else:
        return render(request, 'algorithms/sort.html', {})
```

sort.html

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<div class="search">


        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action=" " style="margin:2%"  >
            <select name="algo_type" style="padding:5%; border-radius:5px;  border: 2px solid #ccc;" placeholder="Type" >
            <option value="bubble">Bubble Sort</option>
            <option value="insertion"> Insertion Sort</option>
            <option value="merge" selected>Merge Sort</option>
            <option value="quick">Quick Sort</option>
            <option value="selection">Selection Sort</option>
            <option value="shell">Shell Sort</option>

                        </select>
<br><br>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="numbers" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Input numbers" />
                </div>
                <br>

        <br>
        <button type="submit">Sort!</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="results"> 
{{results}}

    {% for res in results %}
    <b>{{ res }}</b>

{% endfor %}

</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a list of strings, and they are being sorted as strings. You need to convert them to ints.

```
nums_list = maf_bubble(list(map(int, request.GET['numbers'].split(','))))
```

Comment: Fantastic. I did try `int` but without `map`..and in the wrong place!